# String with delimeter to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string:

```
something.else.is.going.on
```

What I need to do is generate a multidimensional array which should look like this

```
[
     something => [ else => [ is => [ going => [ on => 'HERE I WANT TO PUT A VALUE FROM FUNCTION PARAMETER' ] ] ] ]
]
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = 'something.else.is.going.on';
$separator = '.';
$value = true;

function nestedArray(array $key, $value) {
    if (empty($key))
        return $value;
    return array(array_shift($key) => nestedArray($key, $value));
}

$result = nestedArray(explode($separator, $key), $value);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $string='something.else.is.going.on';
    $exploded_string = explode('.', $string);
    $x = count($exploded_string) - 1;
    $temp = array();
    for($i = $x; $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        $temp = array($exploded_string[$i] => $temp);
    }
    var_dump($temp); ?>
```

Gives you

```
Array
(
    [something] => Array
        (
            [else] => Array
                (
                    [is] => Array
                        (
                            [going] => Array
                                (
                                    [on] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks to [How to create a nested array out of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189073/how-to-create-a-nested-array-out-of-an-array-in-php) for help