# Dynamically creating nested/tree arrays using loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, tree

I want to create a function that will process this array

```
$keys = array(
           array(
             'lev1' => 'Science',
             'lev2' => 'Engineering',
             'lev3' => 'Chemical Engineering'
           )
        );
```

into a tree array like

```
$output = array (
        'Science' => array(
            'Engineering' => array(
                'Chemical Engineering' => array(
                )  
            )
         )
    );
```

I am wondering if this is possible using a loop technique, something that will work even if the number of levels is not fixed (a variable) or unknown so that the output can be created dynamically. I need this for processing database data into a category tree array.

So far, this is what I have:

```
function build_category_tree( $keys, $output ) {

        for ( $x=1; $x<=3; $x++ ) {

            if ( $keys ) {

                $level_key = 'lev' . $x; 
                $id = $keys[$level_key];  

                if ( ! isset( $r[$id] ) ) { 
                    $output[$id] = array( '' );
                }
            }    
        }

       return $output;
}

// Implement the function
$keys = array(
            array(
               'lev1' => 'Science',
               'lev2' => 'Engineering',
               'lev3' => 'Chemical Engineering'
             )
         );

foreach( $keys as $k ) {

    $r = build_category_tree( $k, $r );

}
```

But this does not return my desired $output structure which is typical of a category tree.

Comment: does array has only 3 levels ?

Comment: yes, for this purpose it only has 3

Comment: array(
               'lev1' => 'Science',
               'lev2' => 'Engineering',
               'lev3' => 'Chemical Engineering' , 'lev3'=>'cse'
             ) .will same level comes again ?

Comment: No, they will appear only once. Each node is unique at all levels. The structure I am trying to produce is the above-mentioned $output array. The indices in $keys example are also unique. Basically, I am aiming to create a function that will create $output from $keys

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic array as required. try this let me know

```
<?php
$temp = array();
foreach( $keys as $val => $second) { 
    foreach( $second as $k => $v) {         
         $k.'->'.$v; 
        $temp = array($v => $temp);
    }            
} 
$a=array_reverse($temp);
print_r($temp);
?>
```

output :

```
Array ( [Chemical Engineering] => Array ( [Engineering] => Array ( [Science] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

Comment: array_reverse is not working in my case too. science should be the fist key according to question.

Comment: @MahaDev : same situation :(. any how he itself solved his question

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for what you are trying it. Any how I achieved your expected output. let me know

```
<?php
foreach ($keys as $row) {
    $l1= $row['lev1'];
    $l2=$row['lev2'];
    $l3= $row['lev3'];
}
$new_key[$l1][$l2][$l3]="";
print_r($new_key);
?>
```

output :

```
 Array ( [Science] => Array ( [Engineering] => Array ( [Chemical Engineering] => ) ) )
```

Comment: Not the generalized way. If the level increases more than 3 levels, your code will fail.

Comment: @MahaDev read the comments also. i too asked him. he said level wont increased

Comment: @MahaDev i will satisfy you also dont worry

Comment: Okay sorry, code works fine for three levels. Nice work. (Y)

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to avoid that technique and hope there is another way via loop to accomplish it without manually encoding the three keys to build the array. I am wondering if there is more dynamic way to do it.

Comment: By dynamic way, I mean something that can also work even if the number of levels is not fixed (a variable) or unknown. Sorry for not making it clear in my original post..

Comment: @Edville : have you solved your problem. do you need a dynamic way ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17189190/1679311

```
function catree ( $keys, $res) {

   $t = &$res;        

   foreach ( $keys as $k ) {  

      if ( empty($t[$k] ) ) {  
         $t[$k] = array();   
      }

      $t = &$t[$k];      
  }

  unset($t); 
  return $res;
}

$keys = array (
         array (
        'lev1' => 'Science',
        'lev2' => 'Engineering',
        'lev3' => 'Chemical Engineering'
        ),
        array(
        'lev1' => 'Science',
        'lev2' => 'Engineering',
        'lev3' => 'Industrial Engineering'
        ),
        array(
        'lev1' => 'Science',
        'lev2' => 'Physics',
        'lev3' => 'Practical Physics'
        )
    );

$res = array();
foreach( $keys as $k ) {  
   $res = array_merge( $res, catree( $k , $res ) );
}
```

The output is

```
Array
(
[Science] => Array
    (
        [Engineering] => Array
            (
                [Chemical Engineering] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [Industrial Engineering] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [Physics] => Array
            (
                [Practical Physics] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17189190/1679311. I think it should be like this:

```
$keys = array(
    array(
        'lev1' => 'Science',
        'lev2' => 'Engineering',
        'lev3' => 'Chemical Engineering'
    )
);

$output_array = array();
foreach( $keys as $val => $second) { 
    $second = array_reverse($second);
    foreach( $second as $k => $v) {
        $output_array = array($v => $output_array);
    }            
} 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output_array);
```

//output

```
Array
(
    [Science] => Array
        (
            [Engineering] => Array
                (
                    [Chemical Engineering] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I am actually aiming for Science as the topmost key in the node ( Chemical Engineering is under Engineering. Engineering is under Science )