# PHP PDO combine separate array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have following function which returns multiple rows of data, but it is returning separate arrays:

```
   function getAllDataByID($uid)
   {
   try {  

            $conn = DB::db_connect();
            $sql = "Select id from tbl1 where uid =:uid";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array(':uid'=>$uid));
            $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $query;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }   
   }
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "22"
}
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "21"
}
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "18"
}
```

Whereas I want it to be a nested array.

Comment: What do you mean by _nested array_?  Do you have an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a nested array out of an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189073/how-to-create-a-nested-array-out-of-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Basically, nested means i can access the array like $arr['id'][0],$arr['id'][1], $arr['id'][2] i want to print all the result with loop and with this seperate array's i am not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`, which will return tuples

Answer (score 0):

I am using my custom [Database](https://github.com/oroszlanyzsolt/Database) class for querying, inserting, updating and deleting in short working with my database and it works flawlessly. You do not have to use it but worth check out line 85 `while ($row = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` where I append the row to existing array which will be used to return data in a way you need.