# Add new dimension to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't know how to ask the question.My goal is :

convert :

```
$myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', ....];
```

into :

```
$newArr['a']['b']['c']... = 1;
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a nested array out of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189073/how-to-create-a-nested-array-out-of-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Thanks you all for you valuable love and comments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the value to be assigned, then for-loop backwards over the array:

```
$arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

$result = 1;

for ($i = count($arr) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $result = [ $arr[$i] => $result ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: ok. thanks let me try